# Bogosort function loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting

I want to make bogosort function. I want to invoke the bogo function each time the output is `false`. I tried with `do {bogo function block} while(sorted===false)` loop but looped only once (`arr` changed to empty array). The final goal is to invoke function f.e bogo([1,5,3,2]) and it should output sorted array (in variable `shuffled`).

```js
function bogo(arr) {

  function shuffle(arr) {
    var shuffled = [];
    var rand;
    while (arr.length !== 0) {
      rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
      shuffled.push(arr.splice(rand, 1)[0]);
    }
    return shuffled;
  }

  function sorted(shuffle) {
    for (var i = 0; i < shuffle.length - 1; i++) {
      if (shuffle[i] <= shuffle[i + 1]) {
        continue;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  return sorted(shuffle(arr));
}

console.log(bogo([1, 2]));
```

Comment: your `sorted` function doesn't change anything, how would the array ever get sorted? also, `sorted` returns true or false ... not the (will never be) sorted array

Comment: yes purpose of sorted is to output boolean. On that assumption the while function should take currently shuffled variable and show it but that's only my theory.

Comment: the only `while` in your code is in `shuffle` ... that's run and finished by the time `sorted` is called

Comment: I mean look at this bogo function as first iteration of `while` function that i should add later, but dont know how. Something like `while(bogo(arr)===false){bogo(arr)}`. I hope now you understend what i want to accomplish.

Comment: When i try this code in node js console nad invoke `bogo ([1,2])` it otputs sometimes true sometimes false so this works now it should have been automatically invoked until it gets `true`

Comment: So you want to randomly shuffle the array until it happens to be sorted? *arr* ends up empty because you *splice* all its elements in the shuffle.

Comment: @RobG Yes exacly. Now how to save this parameter ?

Comment: You should understand that bogosort could take a very, very long time for small arrays, and might not ever finish. For example, there are 10! (that's 10 factorial, or about 3.6 million) permutations in an array of 10 items. On average, bogosort will have to try half of them. 100! is about 9*10^157. It's unlikely that you'll see bogosort actually finish with a 100-element array. And, depending on how your random number generator works, it might be impossible to randomly generate all 100! permutations.

Comment: @Jim Mischel I understand that the time to sort rises exponentialy when u add  another value to array. This code is only for learning purposes :)

Comment: Actually, bogosort is factorial time, not exponential time. Just be prepared to kill your program when it starts taking too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to shuffle the array until it's sorted, then you need a loop. You could use *for*, *while* or *do*, I think *do* is more semantic in this case.

Since you destroy the source array during the shuffle, you need to make sure the new shuffled array is passed each time, so:

```js
function bogo(arr) {
  var shuffleCount = 0;
  function shuffle(arr) {
    var shuffled = [];
    var rand;
    while (arr.length !== 0) {
      rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
      shuffled.push(arr.splice(rand, 1)[0]);
    }
    return shuffled;
  }

  function sorted(shuffle) {
    for (var i = 0; i < shuffle.length - 1; i++) {
      if (shuffle[i] <= shuffle[i + 1]) {
        continue;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true
  }
  
  do {
    shuffleCount++;
    arr = shuffle(arr);
  } while (!sorted(arr))
  
  return shuffleCount + ' | ' + arr.join();
}

console.log(bogo([1, 2,3,4]));
```

Comment: @Is there any solution to use initial arr for every shuffling not the shuffled already?

Comment: You need to modify the *shuffle* function to shuffle the array in place, see [*How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)